# Nginx cache path function

Tags: python, cryptography

I have an MD5 hash string:

```
_hash = '743a0e0c5c657d3295d347a1f0a66109'
```

I want to write function that splits passed string to path in nginx cache format:

```
print hash2path(_hash, [1, 2, 3])
# outputs '7/43/a0e/743a0e0c5c657d3295d347a1f0a66109'
```

This is my variant:

```
def hash2path(_hash, levels):
    hash_copy = _hash
    parts = []
    for level in levels:
        parts.append(_hash[:level])
        _hash = _hash[level:]
    parts.append(hash_copy)  
    return '/'.join(parts)
```

How could this be improved?

Answer (score 3):

Why you can't just hardcode cache path calculation?

```
>>> _hash = '743a0e0c5c657d3295d347a1f0a66109'
>>> def hash2path(_hash):
...     return "%s/%s/%s/%s" % (_hash[0], _hash[1:3], _hash[3:6], _hash)
... 
>>> hash2path(_hash)
'7/43/a0e/743a0e0c5c657d3295d347a1f0a66109'
```

UPDATE: If you really need to pass level array there is a little bit faster version:

```
def hash2path(_hash, levels):
    prev = 0
    parts = []
    for level in levels:
        parts.append(_hash[prev:prev + level])
        prev += level
    parts.append(_hash)
    return "/".join(parts)
```

Comment: The point is to pass level array to function

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry. But it doesn't work correct.

Comment: Works if `prev += level` is in 6th line

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't test it thoroughly.